# Angular Form: select a value to update another value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, http-post

I'm using Angular CLI and Angular Material to make a form for posting the data to the API on the server, there are 2 question I want to ask:

1. In the selection list, if user choose "Full", the slider value will be fixed to maximum 100%, if user choose "Optional", the slider value will be normal ( min 10%, max 100% ).
2. In the selection list, if user choose "Full", when they press submit, it will send "0" to the API not the label "Full", if the user choose "Optional", it will send "1" to the API not the label "Optional".

I don't know how to achieve these requirement above, and here is the code that I'm using:

Form.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="createItemForm">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select placeholder="Select" formControlName="modeTaker" id="modeTaker">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let value of modeTakers" value="value">{{ value }}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <span>Percent share</span>
                <mat-slider
                    thumbLabel
                    [displayWith]="formatLabel"
                    min="10"
                    max="100"></mat-slider>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" (click)="createItems()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
    [disabled]="!createItemForm.valid">Create a new items</button>
</form>
```

Form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiService, NotificationService } from '@app/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


createItemForm: FormGroup;
isSubmitting = false;
modeTakers = ['Full', 'Optional'];

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private ns: NotificationService,
    private router: Router
) {
    this.createItemForm= this.formBuilder.group({
      'sharedPercent': [''],
      'modeTaker': ['']
    });
}

formatLabel(value: number) {
    if (value <= 100) {
      return Math.round(value) + '%';
    }
    return value;
}

createItems() {
    const item = Object.assign({}, this.createItemForm.value);
    this.isSubmitting = true;

    this.apiService.post('/itemslist/', item )
    .subscribe(({ name, id }) => {
      this.ns.showNotification(`New ${name} created`);
      this.router.navigate(['/itemslist', id]);
    },
    (error) => {
      this.ns.errorNotification(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: It isn't a problem actually, it's just 2 requirement that I don't know how to solve it

Comment: For 2nd - you can modify the `modeTakers` list by adding `[{text:"Full", value:"0"},{text:"Optional", value:"1"}]`

Comment: Check this demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdqyht

Comment: thank you, is there any way to make the slider react follow the new value has been applied ?

Comment: Unable to understand what you are saying!

Comment: I means when user select "Full", the slider value will be fixed at max (100%), but the slider itself doesn't re-transform to display the max value, its still stay the same, only the value change in the DOM.
That's why I want the slider to re-transform itself to display new value select by user.

Comment: Check the posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For points:

1) You can use `value`, `min` and `max` attribute attribute to binds the values dynamically:

HTML:

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel [displayWith]="formatLabel" [value]="sliderValue" [min]="minValue" [max]="maxValue"></mat-slider>
```

2) Change your JSON to this:

```
[{ text:"Full", value:"0"},{ text:"Optional", value:"1"}]
```

and HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select" id="modeTaker">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let obj of modeTakers" [value]="obj.value" (click)="onchange(obj)">{{ obj.text }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Component.TS Code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "slider-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "slider-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["slider-overview-example.css"]
})
export class SliderOverviewExample {
  maxValue: any;
  minValue: any;
  sliderValue: any;
  modeTakers = [{ text: "Full", value: "0" }, { text: "Optional", value: "1" }];

  onchange(obj: any) {
    if (obj.value == 0) {
      this.sliderValue = 100;
      this.minValue = 10;
      this.maxValue = 100;
    } else {
      this.sliderValue = 50;
      this.minValue = 10;
      this.maxValue = 100;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML markup:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select" id="modeTaker">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let obj of modeTakers" [value]="obj.value" (click)="onchange(obj)">{{ obj.text }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-slider thumbLabel [displayWith]="formatLabel" [value]="sliderValue" [min]="minValue" [max]="maxValue"></mat-slider>
```

[`Online Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdqyht)

Comment: Thank you, this help me alot and your solution is very clean and easy to understand.

Comment: Glat it helped!

Answer (score 0):

1. You will handle the change event of the dropdown list, if the value of the dropdown is 0, you will set the value of the slider as 100. when the value is not 0, we enable the slider. The syntax will be [disabled]="true or false".

2.You should change your modeTakers = [{key: 0, label: 'Full'}, {key: 2, label: 'Optional'}], value will be modeTakers.key and the text will be modeTakers.label

Here is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpa1nw

Comment: Thank you, it's nice to know another way around to handle this type of requirement